Correct Typings for TC39 Decorators with Multiple Kinds
I'm trying to write a logging decorator factory that I can reuse across a class, a method, and an arrow-function field. I'm using TS 5.6, not sure if they include the updated types or not. I've got it working for an arrow-function field using the TS blog post about decorators and 2ality's reference article, but I can't seem to get it to work when I extend it to also support Class and method decorators based on conditions on 'kind':
type Constructor<T = object> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T;

// factory function that returns a decorator
export function log<This, Value, Args extends unknown[], Return>(
  prefix = '[LOG]'
) {
  // return a decorator function
  return function (value: Value | undefined, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext | ClassMethodDecoratorContext | ClassDecoratorContext) {
    const name = String(context.name);

    // class and methods, value is a constructor or a function
    if (context.kind === 'class') {
      const OriginalClass = value as Constructor;
      return class extends OriginalClass {
        constructor(...args: unknown[]) {
          console.log(`${prefix} >> ${name}`);
          console.log(`${prefix} -- ${name} Args: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
          super(...args);
          console.log(`${prefix} << ${name}`);
        }
      }
    }

    if (context.kind === 'method') {
      // with methods you can replace the original function
      return function (this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
        console.log(`${prefix} >> ${name}`);
        console.log(`${prefix} -- ${name} Args: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
        const result = (value as (...args: unknown[]) => unknown).apply(this, args) as Return;
        console.log(`${prefix} << ${name} = ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
        return result;
      };
    }

    // class fields, value is undefined
    if (context.kind === 'field') {
      // with class fields you can only replace the initial value
      return function (this: This, initialValue: Value) {
        if (typeof initialValue === 'function') {
          // if the value is an arrow function, return a new function
          return function (this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
            console.log(`${prefix} >> ${name}`);
            console.log(`${prefix} -- ${name} Args: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
            const result = initialValue.apply(this, args) as Return;
            console.log(`${prefix} << ${name} = ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
            return result;
          };
        }

        // fallback to the initial value
        return initialValue;
      };
    }

    // fallback to the original value
    return value;
  };
}

@log('[CLASS]')
class Hello {
  #name: string;

  constructor(private name?: string) {
    this.#name = name ?? 'World!';
  }

  @log('[METHOD]')
  method() {
    return `Hello, ${this.#name}!`;
  }

  @log('[AFF]')
  aff = () => `Hello, ${this.#name}!`;
}

// check for correct value and binding
const hello = new Hello('Name!');
const aff = hello.aff;

console.log(hello.method());
console.log(hello.aff());
console.log(aff());

It seems to behave correctly, but the TS error that pops up in my IDE is along these lines, which I'm not sure how to fix:
Decorator function return type 'typeof Hello | typeof (Anonymous class) | ((this: unknown, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown) | ((this: unknown, initialValue: typeof Hello) => typeof Hello | ((this: unknown, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown)) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'void | typeof Hello'.
  Type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'void | typeof Hello'.
    Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
      Type 'new (...args: unknown[]) => log<unknown, typeof Hello, unknown[], unknown>.(Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'new (name?: string | undefined) => Hello'.
        Type 'log<unknown, typeof Hello, unknown[], unknown>.(Anonymous class)' is missing the following properties from type 'Hello': #name, method, aff. ts(1270)


Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and see the issue clearly. Right now this code compiles without issue so presumably it's when you actually use it that you run into problems. Can you show code that uses it along with an explicit description of the difference between actual and expected behavior? It would also help if you remove dependencies on anything external to typescript, like node:util, unless you tag the question as being specifically about node (which I expect is not the intent)

@jcalz, okay I've updated

I'd say most of the generics in there aren't helping you, especially since you are doing lots of type assertions. The only one that would do anything worthwhile is Value, and the important part is that your function should return Value no matter what. If I make that happen as shown here then the errors go away. Does that fully address the question? If so then I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Yes it works! Thanks! I'm no TS expert so those generics are just copy pasted from the "Writing Well-Typed Decorators" section of that TS blog mentioned in the question. And I was able to modify it slightly and still have no errors with typescript-eslint using tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked by replacing any with unknown and Function with (...args: unknown[]) => unknown and explicitly casting of 'result' to Value, so it's perfect :)

(...args: unknown[]) => unknown is not a top type for functions (or at least it shouldn't be), so you'd be better off with (...args: never) => unknown as described here. I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Most of the generic type parameters in your function aren't doing you any good at all. TS's support for ES Decorators still doesn't support any sort of mutation of the types of the decorated thing (so microsoft/TypeScript#4881 is still open), so the type being output by the function returned by log() really can only be the type of its first argument or void.  And since the implementation of your function is using type assertions to say that functions are of types related to the generic type parameters, and since those type parameters are declared on log() and not on the function it returns, in practice they are doing nothing.
The only generic type parameter that matters is Value. You want the function returned by log() to accept an input of type Value and to return an output of type Value. All the other types are up to you, but this is the important bit:
function log(prefix = '[LOG]') {
  return function <Value>(
    value: Value, 
    context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext | ClassMethodDecoratorContext | ClassDecoratorContext
  ): Value {
     // impl
  }
}

Note that I moved the scope of the generic type parameter from log to the returned function. That's so you're not asking TypeScript to use contextual typing to infer Value.  The way you have it now works fine if you write
@log('[CLASS]')
class Hello { 
}

but will fail if you write the ostensibly equivalent
const logClass = log('[CLASS]');
@logClass
class Hello {
}

If you move Value to the returned function, then logClass above will still be generic and Value will be inferred when you use the @logClass decorator, instead of failing with a Value of unknown.

So that's how log() should look to callers.  As for the implementation, you might need to use type assertions on your return statements so that TS accepts that it's of type Value, but again, you're already using those, so it's not really losing any type safety:
function log(prefix = '[LOG]') {
  // return a decorator function
  return function <Value>(
    value: Value,
    context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext | ClassMethodDecoratorContext | ClassDecoratorContext
  ): Value {

    if (context.kind === 'class') {
      const OriginalClass = value as Constructor;
      return class extends OriginalClass { ⋯ } as Value
    }

    if (context.kind === 'method') {
      return function (this: any, ...args: any) { ⋯ } as Value;
    }

    if (context.kind === 'field') {
      return function (this: any, initialValue: Value) { ⋯ } as Value;
    }

    return value;
  };
}

And again, you can use types other than any, or Function, or anything you need. It's possible you might decide at some point to more strongly type things, but they aren't necessary for the decorators to work from the call site.
Playground link to code
